# date is converted into datetime format when stored in datatable ado.net

Tags: c#, datetime, dataset

I had written stored procedure which returns date only not datetime i.e

CurrentDate
2013-10-06

So when i stored this result in dataset using da.fill( ) method, there inside the datatable it is stored in the format datetime resulting as 2013-10-06 12:00:00

How to solve this problem?

Comment: The only 'problem' is formatting. Configure the Column.

Comment: There is no Date type in .NET only a `DateTime`, therefore the `Date` database-type is converted into the CLR type `DateTime`. You should format the column in the grid.

Answer (score 3):

Thank You all guys, finally i followed this approach

```
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    dr["date"] = DateTime.Parse((dr["date"].ToString())).ToShortDateString();
                }
```

Which only returns date without time.

Answer (score 1):

A datetime is always stored with default time value as "12:00:00",u can only format it to your desire format,

```
ds.Table[0].rows[0][0].tostring("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: instead of looping through all the rows is there anyway to format entire column.

Comment: I don't think so,as .net doesn't have variable with only Date

Answer (score 0):

You can format the DateTime string to show only Date. Since .NET doesn't have a Date-Only Datatype, you have to filter the Date out of a DateTime object.
Choose the `ToShortDateString()` Method and if you need a special format, then you have to use the `ToString()` method and provide a format string which can be found easily if you google for "DateTime Format".

Comment: You can store date-only in SQL, but not in .NET

Answer (score 0):

`SqlDateTime` class may be helpful